# Android (AndEngine) - Leadbolt Notification slow down my app

Tags: android, andengine, leadbolt

I have a problem with a **[Leadbolt](http://www.leadbolt.com)** notification.

Leadbolt starts to slow down my application (I tried it on my two applications) each 10-15 seconds when it doesn't have an internet connection on my phone.

Does anyone know why this happens?

My code:

**Manifest** File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application>
   ...
   <receiver android:name="com.Leadbolt.AdNotification" />
</application>
```

Main Activity:

```
import com.Leadbolt.AdController;

@Override
public Engine onLoadEngine() {

AdController myController;
myController = new AdController(getApplicationContext(),"MY_APP_ID");
myController.setAsynchTask(true);
myController.loadNotification();
...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult to suggest a solution without more information, it is possible Leadbolt is causing the problem, but equally it could be caused by some combination of your application and Leadbolt. You could try using this application resource optimizer tool for Android to track down where the problem is. You can get it here https://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=9700312